# Movie does not load

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayer

I am trying to play a simple mp4 File in a ViewController on viewDidLoad. If i run the code, url path seems to be correct but the movie loads and loads. The weirds thing is, if i run the same code in a different XCode-Project, it works.(same settings)

Any ideas ???

PS: I already tried different ways to set url or load the movie. Path, Build Phases and mp4 file already checked.

Heres my viewDidLoad:

`- (void)viewDidLoad {`

```
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo.mp4" ofType:nil];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController =[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];    

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                          object:[playerViewController moviePlayer]];

[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

NSLog(@"%@", url);

//---play movie---
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
//[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
player.scalingMode =MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[player play];

}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use [super viewDidLoad] as the last coomand?

Comment: I already saw this post and tried it that way. Anyway no changes :-/
kind of frustrating..

Comment: Actually i think the player is working fine so far. The problems seems to be the file itself. But where do i have to search if both path's are correct ??

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo.mp4" ofType:nil];
```

You must change to this:

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" ofType:@"mp4"];
```

Also try to comment this because i think the method is being called by  the notification `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`:

```
movieFinishedCallback:
```

Comment: No changes. Problem still remains. Tried to set url in a few different ways.

Comment: I don't believe that is a problem.  I have used code like this and it has worked just fine.  The `type` parameter is not required.  In fact this is from the documentation "If extension is an empty string or nil, the extension is assumed not to exist and the file is the first file encountered that exactly matches name."

Comment: what is the content of movieFinishedCallback: ?

Comment: At the moment there is no content in movieFinishedCallback. Later it will be used to animate other objects.

Comment: does viewWillDissapear  contain something? I have tried to run this code and it works fine.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use [super viewDidLoad] as the last command/after the player starts playing?

Comment: @ratul anyway that should be the first line in viewDidLoad.

Comment: oh yeah thats actually wrong. its in the first line

Comment: Not necessarily... but in this case i think it should be the first line and try to start playing in view did/will appear.